# Typo3 - bulkInsert from a scheduled command - where should the code reside?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, insert, typo3, bulkinsert

I have created an extension using Extension Builder. This has created my necessary table and repository and controllers files.

I have created a command class with a method that is called once a day (via the scheduler extension). The purpose of the command is to truncate a table and replace the data with a bulk insert of new rows.

I have found example code for a bulkInsert however I am not sure where I should put it?

I originally assume putting it in the Controller was the logical solution, but perhaps there is a better place to put it? Or a better way to run a bulk insert?

A bulk insert requires me to provide the table name, ie where "testTable" is the table name I could make the connection like so:

```
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('testTable');
```

...but connecting to the table name like this doesn't feel right as the rest of the extension utilises the repository. It feels a bit disjointed.

Can anybody give me any guidance on where and how I should do this to keep my source code nice and tight.

Comment: Does the data in testTable belong to the domain / a domain model? (domain as in DDD)

Comment: Yes it does. testTable is actually called "Mitarbeiter", and has a model of "Mitarbeiter.php", a "MitarbeiterController.php" and a "MitarbeiterRepository.php"

Comment: You sould create a "regular" Extbase raw query in the MitarbeiterRepository: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make a separate instance of the table connection like so:

```
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable($tblname);
```

and then to utilise the "bulkInsert" tool, passing over the table name (again), an array of records and an array of the associated field names

```
$connection->bulkInsert($tblname, $records, $fieldnames);
```

It would be nice to have bulkInsert available directly via the respository but I'm sure there is some logical reason why that isn't possible. But this solution works well anyway.